# CSS 3-column center-expanding layout that collapses nicely

Tags: css, multiple-columns, fluid-layout, liquid-layout

**Edit 2:** Another way to describe what I want might be: 3 column, fixed left, expanding center, min-max right. I just don't want the right to be fixed; I want it to collapse to a min when the window shrinks. I've tried with `table`s, and 3-4 ways with `div`s and nothing works...

---

**Edit 3:** This is what I have so far: http://jsfiddle.net/Rw8BZ/

1. Best centering, bad wrapping. I want the pink element to shrink/wrap before the green.
2. Good wrapping, good width, bad centering. Tables. Maybe usable with a margin.
3. Good wrapping, bad width, bad centering.

...and it just gets worse from there. The colors are for illustration, it's a uniform bg color.

---

I'm trying to find/create a 3-column layout (CSS2 unfortunately) where the left and right are compact and the center is elastic and centered *relative to the other columns*. IOW, like how `<table>` used to work if the center `<td>` was `width=100%`. So, I'm currently using `display: table`, which almost works.

What I want to happen when the width shrinks is everything to shrink with the center column still being centered, but when there's no room left, the right-side starts to wrap. However, using `width=100%` in the center to get that centered between the columns makes the right column collapse immediately. If I don't use `width=100%` in the center, the right column expands and the center is no longer centered between the other columns. Neither `min-width` nor `max-width` seemed to work in the right column to nudge it into doing what I want...

**Edit 1:** If I change it to use max-width on the right, no `width=100%` in the center, the right side collapses as I want but when expanded doesn't keep the width--the right column just grows proportionally.

The pseudo-content is:

```
<div id="header">
  <div><img width=214px></div>
  <div>Some text, 3 lines, 2-3 words each</div>
  <div><ul><li><a>menu</a></li>...</ul><div><img><img><img></div></div>
</div>
```

The left column is an image, center some text, and right a short line of links over some small icon images. The list is styled to be a horizontal list, like a menu.

The CSS I currently have is:

```
div#header, div#header * {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}
div#header {
    display: table;
    font-family: FranklinGothic,Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    width: 100%;
}
div#header > div {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: top;
}
div#header > div:first-child + div {
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
}
div#header > div:first-child + div + div {
    text-align: right;
    white-space: nowrap;
    background-color: blue;
}
div#header li {
    padding-left: 1em;
}
div#header li:first-child {
    padding-left: 0 !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I generally use jQuery Layout plugin for this types of layout. Not pure css, but using a few lines of javascript you can create very flexible layouts quickly responding to resizes and even rotation on mobile devices.

The documentation is very extensive and i found it to have a quitte steep learning curve before you can write a layout yourself without looking at the docs, but once you get used to it, I think you'll simply love it.

http://layout.jquery-dev.net